# Is it possible to unmount a partition table?

Tags: partition, partition-table

Is it possible to unmount a partition table so I only see sda and not sda1 and sda2 in /dev?

Background:

I know a partition table is not mounted.
But I did not find a better name for this.

I often use *dd* to overwrite a hard disk or an usb pen.
But they often have some partitions on it. And after overwriting I can still see the old (no longer existing) partition table using *lsblk*.

I know it's possible to reread the partition table using *partprobe*.

But I wonder if it is possible to unmount the partition table *before* overwriting the usb pen. Because I don't want a programm to access a corrupt partition while overwriting with *dd*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `partx`'s `-d` option to tell the kernel to forget about partitions. For example, `partx -d /dev/sda` will make `/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sda2`, ... go away (temporarily). They'll show up again next time the kernel is made to re-scan the partition table.

Another option is `delpart`: `delpart /dev/sda 1; delpart /dev/sda 2` should do it (but the `partx` syntax is nicer).

A third option is to wipe the partition table first then let the kernel reread it; any partition table editor tool (e.g., `sfdisk`, `gdisk`, etc.) could be used, or `wipefs` (which will do partition tables, not just filesystems).